# Boost symbol not found

Tags: exception, boost, ld, throw

I'm trying to compile/port an older version of OpenOffice.  It uses Boost v1.34.1, which is part of the source tree.  The error message is as follows:

```
Undefined symbols:
  "boost::throw_exception(std::exception const&)", referenced from:
      boost::detail::shared_count::shared_count<ScToken>(ScToken*)in detfunc.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
```

Boost is new to me, and I haven't been able to find much online to help me understand this.  From the error message, I understand that I probably need to link a library.  However, `boost::throw_exception` is defined in a header file with no matching library (that I can find).  Just for kicks, I've tried `#include <boost/throw_exception.hpp>` in detfunc and using symbolic links to put the header file in the same directory with no luck.

Is there a library I should be linking with `-l` or an include path with `-I`?  How should I get that symbol referenced in?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Boost expects the project either to be built with macro `BOOST_NO_EXCEPTIONS` undefined, or to define the function `boost::throw_exception` itself.

From `<boost/throw_exception.hpp>` in version 1.34.1:

```
namespace boost
{

#ifdef BOOST_NO_EXCEPTIONS

void throw_exception(std::exception const & e); // user defined

#else

//[Not user defined --Dynguss]
template<class E> inline void throw_exception(E const & e)  
{
    throw e;
}

#endif

} // namespace boost
```

Boost's configuration headers will determine whether to define the macro or not. It looks like it boils down to the compiler you're using, but there may be other factors. Take a look in the `boost/config/compiler/` folder for the header file that corresponds to your compiler, then search for `BOOST_NO_EXCEPTIONS` in it. There should be some conditions around the `#define` to help explain when Boost defines it. You may be able to configure your build to avoid the definition and get past the linker error you're experiencing.

If you're unable to change your compiler config to avoid the definition, then you're probably left defining `boost::throw_exception(std::exception const & e)` yourself somewhere in the OpenOffice code. I'm unfamiliar with that code, though, so I can't give a good suggestion where it should go.

Comment: Thanks!  I had eventually read through `throw_exception.hpp` and already discovered precisely what you answered.  I wasn't aware of `boost/config/compiler/` for the compiler flags, but sure enough, `BOOST_NO_EXCEPTIONS` was defined.